# Confidence Interval for a proportion, with false negatives/positives

Tags: confidence-interval, proportion

I have a fairly simple problem but haven't been able to find any resources with the solution.

Let's say we have a population of N subjects. We get a sample of size n, and within that sample we have k 'positives' (and thus n-k negatives). Now, we're interested in computing a confidence interval on the probability of getting a positive, and there's lots of methods to choose from (Agresti-Coull, Clopper-Pearson, etc.)

Now the twist is that the process that determines positives and negatives can produce false positive and negatives with a known probability. Assume we know the false positive (fpr) and false negative rate (fnr) of the process. In that case, how do we calculate the confidence interval for the proportion of true positives?

Comment: It seems mixture models would be a good place to start... your count of observed positives results from a mixture of the probability that you record a negative when negative (and I suppose positive when positive) and the underlying probability of positive. I suspect that there are clear frequentist CI for this type of problem.

Comment: One thing that may be tricky is dealing with very different fpr and fnr.